# How can i shape a button with matplotlib widget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, widget

I would like to smooth the edges of the button, change the default rectangular shape.

This is the code I used to create the button:

```
axImg = plt.axes([0.25, 0.45, 0.2, 0.09])

bnI = Button(axImg, 'Enter', color='0.9')

bnI.hovercolor = "blue"

bnI.label.set_fontsize(18),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot shape the button itself, because it is essentially just an axes, and axes are rectangular. (Of course one could use different axes, like polar ones, but that would be completely round then.)

One can however place a `FancyBboxPatch` into the axes, and give that some round edges.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

bttn_ax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.45, 0.2, 0.09])
bttn_ax.set_frame_on(False)

bttn = Button(bttn_ax, 'Enter')
bttn.label.set_fontsize(18)

fancybox = mpatches.FancyBboxPatch((0,0), 1,1, 
                                   edgecolor="black",
                                   facecolor="0.9",
                                   boxstyle="round,pad=0.1", 
                                   mutation_aspect=3, 
                                   transform=bttn_ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
bttn_ax.add_patch(fancybox)

bttn.on_clicked(lambda x: print("Click!"))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that hovering will not work in this case, because what is shown is the patch, not the axes.